# Myspace Profile 2 CSS question (HTML Box Module)

Tags: css, myspace

does anybody know how to remove the small grey lines from the HTML Box Module from myspace profile 2.0 via css?

I just can't figure out how to select it div.htmlboxMODULE does not seam to work.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tr {background-color: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

div.htmlBoxModule {}.... upper case "B" & "M"